# Ruby method Dir.glob not returning list of files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Dir.glob to return a list of files as follows:

file_location = "/path/to/file/"

@files = Dir.glob{"#(file_location)*")

This works fine when I run my application in development mode using the WEBrick server.  However when I run my application in production mode on the same server using apache and passenger it does not retrieve the files that are located in that directory.  Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
file_location = "/path/to/file/"

@files = Dir["#{file_location}*"]
```

Comment: Thx for the response.  This also worked to retrieve the files in a directory.  My real issue was that apache did not have permission to access the directory which is why it was not working on production.